# 'else' cannot start a statement. [MiscellanousFIles.csproj]

Tags: c#

I'm new to programming guys (C#) my code says that the if else statement that I used is causing an error. Idk what the problem is with this. Can someone help me please?

```
    if(ItemPrice==Soda);
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Inserted so far: P0 out of P{Soda}");
        break;
    }
    else if(ItemPrice==Juice);
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Inserted so far: P0 out of P{Juice}");
    }
    else if(ItemPrice==WaterBottle);
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Inserted so far: P0 out of P{WaterBottle}");
    }
```

Comment: Remove ; after your if and else if statement, rest looks good

Answer (score 7):

You have semicolons (`;`) after your if statements, Which gives you these warnings

[Compiler Warning (level 3) CS0642](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0642)

> Possible mistaken empty statement
>
> A semicolon after a conditional statement may cause your code to
>   execute differently than intended.

And this error

[Compiler Error CS1513](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs1513)

> `}` expected
>
> The compiler expected a closing curly brace (`}`) that was not found.

The syntax you needed

```
if (condition) 
{
   // statement;
}
else if (condition) 
{
   // statement;
}
else if (condition) 
{
   // statement;
}
```

---

**Additional resources**

[if-else (C# Reference)](http://v)